# What species is this golden fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Last summer I was visited by this unusual golden fly, whose kind I have never seen before. It was impossible to scare away so I could take relatively good pictures.

The pictures on [this hobbyist page](https://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_muscoid/GoldenHairedBlowfly.htm) suggest, it is a  "Golden blowfly". Those pictures were taken in Australia. The [only paper](https://www.publish.csiro.au/is/it9941343) I could find on golden blowflies locates the species in Australia as well. However, I took my pictures in southern Germany.

What is this fly? Is it an invasive species or native to Germany as well as Australia?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it tachina fera?